# Affect a table when I change an other table

Tags: dart

My question is why does `tb1` change the value of `tb2`?
And what can I do so it doesn't affect `tb1` when I change a value in `tb2`?

Thank you for your help

```
void main() {
  List tb1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  print(tb1); //[1, 2, 3, 4]
  List tb2 = tb1;
  print(tb2); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
  tb1[2] = 10;

  print(tb1); //[1, 2, 10, 4]
  print(tb2); //[1, 2, 10, 4]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tb1` is a reference to a list. When you are doing:

```
List tb2 = tb1;
```

You are copying the reference so `tb2` and `tb1` points to the same `List` instance. If you want to clone the `List` you can call `.toList()` to your existing list:

```
void main() async {
  List tb1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  print(tb1); //[1, 2, 3, 4]
  List tb2 = tb1.toList();
  print(tb2); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
  tb1[2] = 10;

  print(tb1); //[1, 2, 10, 4]
  print(tb2); //[1, 2, 3, 4]
}
```

`tb2` will now point to a copy of the `tb1` list. Be aware that the `List` are copied and not each element of the list. In this case it is not a problem since numbers are immutable but if you have objects where the inner state can be changed, you need to make some logic to copy each object (if you don't want the two lists to point to the same object instances).

I should also add that you code does have a type problem where you remove the generic part of the `List` type. So instead of using `List<int>` you are doing `List` which is the same as `List<dynamic>`.

The type system can help you a lot if you let it use the full correct type (so Dart can e.g. ensure that you list are only going to contain int values) so I will recommend write you code like this:

```
void main() async {
  final tb1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  print(tb1); //[1, 2, 3, 4]
  final tb2 = tb1.toList();
  print(tb2); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
  tb1[2] = 10;

  print(tb1); //[1, 2, 10, 4]
  print(tb2); //[1, 2, 3, 4]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand why is not work for me :(

In my script i do it

```
print('BEFORE+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++');
print(decoded[param]['quiz'][start]['answers']);
if(check.length==0) {
  result=[];
  List st = decoded[param]['quiz'][start]['answers'].toList();
  check = st.toList();
  for(int i=0;i<check.length;i++) {
      check[i]['value']=false;
      result.add(false);
  }
  print('AFTER+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++');
  print(st);
}
```

**Here the result print** you can see London change to false

BEFORE+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

[{answer: Rome, value: false}, {answer: London, value: true}, {answer: Marseille, value: false}]

AFTER+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

[{answer: Rome, value: false}, {answer: London, value: false}, {answer: Marseille, value: false}]

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found this good solution for me

```
 List tb1 = [1,2,3,4];
 List tb2 = [];
 
 tb2 = List.of(tb1);
 print(tb1);
 print(tb2);

 tb1[2]=10;
 print(tb1);
 print(tb2);

 tb1[0]=12;
 print(tb1);
 print(tb2);
```